# Как сохранить фигуры в ексель файле после обработки

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

Библиотекой `phpspreadsheet` вношу изменения в **.xls** файл (шаблон). Изначально в этом шаблоне присутствуют фигуры:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После сохранения файла:

```
$writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xls');
$writer->save('out2.xls');
```

Рисунок(фигуры) пропадают:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как их сохранить чтобы они оставались в файле после его редактирования?

Comment: такая же проблема. удалось решить?

Comment: @AndreyMihalev покуда нет(